# Game Center login alert did finish

Tags: ios, game-center

Is there a method I can call to update a label when the user presses cancel on the login alert or successfully logs into the game center.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `authenticateWithCompletionHandler:` on the local `GKPlayer`, you can update the label in the completion handler block (if the user cancels you'll get a non nil `NSError` in the completion handler).

**EDIT:**

As pointed in the comment, this method is deprecated in iOS6, instead, you should set the `authenticateHandler` on the local `GKPlayer`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply however I think that it is depreciated in iOS 6?

Comment: Good point, I didn't know this.
It seems the way to go now is setting the `authenticateHandler` instead.